# Haskell project dependency installation

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm learning Haskell and I keep running into dependency problems when trying to run any project that isn't a simple single file tutorial-like file(aka, a real project).

The one I'm currently fighting with is a tetris clone I thought would be fun and interesting to learn from.  [Description of game](http://scrambledeggsontoast.github.io/2014/09/23/tetris-netwire/) and [code at github](https://github.com/ScrambledEggsOnToast/tetris-hs)

I cloned the repo and ran `cabal install` and got

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: tetris-hs-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
next goal: base (dependency of tetris-hs-0.1.0.0)
rejecting: base-4.5.0.0/installed-40b... (conflict: tetris-hs => base>=4.6 && <4.8)
rejecting: base-4.7.0.1, 4.7.0.0, 4.6.0.1, 4.6.0.0, 4.5.1.0, 4.5.0.0, 4.4.1.0,
4.4.0.0, 4.3.1.0, 4.3.0.0, 4.2.0.2, 4.2.0.1, 4.2.0.0, 4.1.0.0, 4.0.0.0,
3.0.3.2, 3.0.3.1 (global constraint requires installed instance)
```

I have no idea what this means, so I started searching for steps on setting up projects and landed on the [cabal user guide](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html). Started playing with variations of `runhaskell Setup.hs configure --user` and got a list of missing dependencies.  When I try to install them with `cabal install foo`, sometimes it works, most of the time I get an error, ranging from things like, "Its already installed" to "There is no package named 'Foo'".  One interesting one was after I installed netwire, I tried to install lens, and it replies, "cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
netwire-5.0.0"

If I try to just run `runhaskell Main.hs` it says, "Could not find module `Graphics.GLUtil'" and if I try to install Graphics.GLUtil, Graphics, or GLUtil, it says that there is no package of that name.

I need a cabal for dummies book or something.

EDIT:
After updating ghc and cabal, I ran `cabal install` again and it started installing everything but after a few minutes it hit a bump and spit out this:

```
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
FTGL-2.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
GLFW-b-1.4.6 depends on bindings-GLFW-3.0.3.3 which failed to install.
GLUtil-0.8.2 depends on vector-0.10.11.0 which failed to install.
JuicyPixels-3.1.7.1 depends on vector-0.10.11.0 which failed to install.
adjunctions-4.2 depends on distributive-0.4.4 which failed to install.
bifunctors-4.1.1.1 depends on distributive-0.4.4 which failed to install.
bindings-GLFW-3.0.3.3 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
comonad-4.2.2 depends on distributive-0.4.4 which failed to install.
distributive-0.4.4 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
free-4.9 depends on distributive-0.4.4 which failed to install.
graphics-drawingcombinators-1.5 depends on FTGL-2.0 which failed to install.
lens-4.4.0.2 depends on vector-0.10.11.0 which failed to install.
linear-1.10.1.2 depends on vector-0.10.11.0 which failed to install.
profunctors-4.2.0.1 depends on distributive-0.4.4 which failed to install.
semigroupoids-4.2 depends on distributive-0.4.4 which failed to install.
tetris-hs-0.1.0.0 depends on vector-0.10.11.0 which failed to install.
vector-0.10.11.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

When I try to `cabal install vector`:

```
[ 5 of 19] Compiling Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream.Monadic ( Data/Vector/Fusion/Stream/Monadic.hs,    dist/build/Data/Vector/Fusion/Stream/Monadic.o )
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package primitive-0.5.3.0 ... <command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: libHSprimitive-0.5.3.0.so (libHSprimitive-0.5.3.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
vector-0.10.11.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: IMHO you should consider using [cabal sandboxes](http://coldwa.st/e/blog/2013-08-20-Cabal-sandbox.html) (ignore the part with the build ghc stuff) - there you can play around with `--force-reinstalls` without much danger and it usually just works if you did not install to much into your local rep. before. For the new error itself: try installing the first offending (here: `vector`) package directly and post the errors there

Comment: to test a sandbox execute this commands in the folder where your projects .cabal file is located: `cabal sandbox init` then `cabal install --dependencies-only` (or even `cabal install --dependencies-only --force-reinstalls` and test if this helps (it probably will)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a full explanation, but I'll point out the problem and interpret things for you.

```
next goal: base (dependency of tetris-hs-0.1.0.0)
rejecting: base-4.5.0.0/installed-40b... (conflict: tetris-hs => base>=4.6 && <4.8)
```

`next goal: base.` "Next goal" is silly fluff; cabal is just thinking out loud. Read that as "trying to satisfy this package."

`rejecting: base-4.5.0.0/installed-`... This is the version you have installed.

`conflict: tetris-hs => base>=4.6`... Version 4.5 won't work, because `tetris-hs` requires >=4.6.

And then the rest of the message states, roughly, that you're not allowed to install more than one version of `base`.

`base`, unsurprisingly, is *the* fundamental package; among other things, it's wired into GHC itself in various ways. So what this all boils down to is that your version of GHC is too old for the version listed in the package cabal file. You can either install the latest Haskell Platform, or try editing the `.cabal` file to allow older versions--but don't be surprised if compilation fails for other reasons.

*Edit*: Read the other comments about cabal sandboxes. Sandboxes are not directly relevant to your question, but if you understand and use them, you'll avoid a whole category of confusing cabal problems in the future.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help.  My GHC is 7.4.1 and the latest is 7.8.3 so hopefully upgrading will solve my problem.

Comment: @JakeSellers You should definitely update, there's actually a good handful of new features to try out.

Comment: @bheklilr, I can't seem to find an easy way to update, do I need to uninstall and install from source again?

Comment: @JakeSellers That's what I usually do.  You can theoretically do side-by-side installations, but depending on your platform that can be difficult.  I've never had many problems just nuking my install, backing up my .cabal directory in my home folder, and starting from scratch.

Comment: After I got some time tonight I reinstalled ghc and cabal and that problem has been resolved.  However, there are now new errors, I'll edit the post but it may be best for me to just create a new question.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I don't think the new errors are related either to the original question or to the sandboxing issue. Probably best to move it to a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the comment of Carsten König:

- [hsenv](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsenv)

> hsenv (linux or MacOS) is a tool (inspired by Python's virtualenv) to create isolated Haskell environments.

This is the one I am currently using an I find it quite nice. What I like about it is the ability to keep using the standard commands

I haven't tried different versions of GHC with it yet but it's mentioned on their page under 'Advanced usage'

- [cabal-sandbox](http://coldwa.st/e/blog/2013-08-20-Cabal-sandbox.html)

> Sandboxes allow to build packages in isolation by creating a private package environment for each package. If you are familiar with Python’s virtualenv or Ruby’s RVM, this is a Haskell analogue.

Not sure if you can have different versions of ghc with cabal sandbox...

- [Nix](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-02-04-how-i-develop-with-nixos.html)

If you're on linux or MaxOS, there is a third option which I didn't know about myself until recently. If you read through the post you'll see that you *can* but don't *have* to use the full NixOS.

> Nix: the package manager that installs software, and the associated programming language. This project can be installed on any Linux distribution, along with OS X.
>
> Nixpkgs: the common repository of software that defines how to install GHC, Emacs, etc.
>
> In this article, we’ll only be focusing on Nix and Nixpkgs, so you should be able to use these techniques even if you don’t want to run NixOS (but you totally should run NixOS).

Comment: that's the best part of the sandboxes: you can use all the cabal commands, have a repl/ghci (cabal repl), etc. - Nix is great (still  have to look into it) and hsenv I do not know - I used cabal-dev in the past but now completly switched to sandboxes.

Comment: btw: I don't think a new haskeller will have multiple GHC installations or really want to dive into Nix - but who knows?